# Adjust width and height of a control to wrap its content

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

How can I do to set the Width/Height of a Windows Phone control to be just the minimum necessary to wrap its content?
In Android I would have done it the following way:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could use a ViewBox. This will scale the content inside to fit the space available.

```
<ViewBox>
    <Grid Width="Auto" Height="Auto"> 
    <!-- Your content goes here -->
    <Grid/>
<ViewBox/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Controls have some properties wich you can make use of: *MinWidth*, *MaxWidth*, *Width*, some controls with text content have also *TextWrapping* and *TextTrimming*. By using those you will probably achieve what you want - some examples:

```xml
<StackPanel Margin="20">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,10"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="Simple long description"/>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Border> <!-- Implicit width -->
        <TextBlock Width="150"/>
    </Border>
    <Border> <!-- Implicit width with text wrapping -->
        <TextBlock Width="150" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </Border>
    <Border> <!-- Auto width -->
        <TextBlock Width="Auto"/>
    </Border>
    <Border> <!-- Auto width but with limit -->
        <TextBlock Width="Auto" MaxWidth="180"/>
    </Border>
    <Border> <!-- Short text with min width -->
        <TextBlock Width="Auto" MinWidth="100" Text="Min"/>
    </Border>
    <Button> <!-- Button with wrapped text -->
        <TextBlock Width="120" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

The result:

[image]

In some cases you will probably also what to use `HorizontalAlignment = Stretch` which will set control's width to available space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `width="Auto"` and `height="Auto"` attribute of the respective controls.

For example

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Width="Auto" Text="Sample Text" />
</StackPanel>
```